# In 'IPL A80', what is A80? (Starting a mainframe operating system)

Tags: mainframe

Just toying around with IBM mainframe emulation using Hercules. To launch zOS, the command command: `ipl a80` is entered. IPL means initial program load. But I couldn't figure out the meaning of the parameter `a80`. What does it mean?

Comment: Did you Google? I got 83,700 hits for "hercules ipl a80". You should have been able to figure out what the a80 is. If you are trying to use zOS and you have not bought a licenece then we cannot help you further. Try the hercules web site - but the same condition would apply (no illegal software).

Comment: @NicC is correct if you are using a host OS like z/OS or an OCO dust.  If you are using a Linux Distro or other software you will need to verify the license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A80 refers to the unit address of the device you are IPLing.  In the case of Hercules, it is a reference to a virtual device that contains a volume.  This volume contains the `RES` pack or system residence volume.  Effectively the boot disk.

As pointed out, the version of the operating system your attempting to IPL needs to be one that is considered open source to avoid legal issues.  At some point MVS SP went from open to closed and this point is referred to as the transition to Object Code Only (OCO).  Any version that is OCO requires a license from IBM and other vendors potentially to use it in an ambulatory.

Note, other operating systems like Linux can be used so you need to very the OS license to ensure your compliant legally.

Good luck and welcome to the mainframe!

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can use IBM z Development and Test (zD&T), which is now the commercial version of the old Hercules systems, and is supported by IBM under software maintenence.

When you boot with the IPL A80 under zD&T, just as the one above mentioned, it refers to a local volume, which you map with a mapping file. Here is an exerpt of the device map for my zD&T system:

```
[manager]
name awsckd 0001
device 0A80 3390 3390 /z/A3RES1
device 0A81 3390 3390 /z/A3RES2
device 0A82 3390 3390 /z/A3SYS1
device 0A83 3390 3390 /z/A3BLZ1
device 0A84 3390 3390 /z/A3PAGA
device 0A85 3390 3390 /z/A3PAGB
device 0A86 3390 3390 /z/A3PAGC
device 0A87 3390 3390 /z/A3PRD1
device 0A88 3390 3390 /z/A3PRD2
device 0A89 3390 3390 /z/A3PRD3
device 0A8A 3390 3390 /z/A3USR1
device 0A8B 3390 3390 /z/A3USS1
device 0A8C 3390 3390 /z/A3USS2
```

The file /z/A3RES1 is the bootable volume on my system. You can find more information in the knowledge center: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTQBD_12.0.0/com.ibm.zdt.nav.doc/topics/product_family_welcome.html

Comment: IBM's site says that zD&T is **Starting at $4,920.00 USD per year**. Holy crap! Is there no open source / cheaper option?

Comment: Considering that it comes with and entire z/OS stack, and current software including CICS, IMS, DB2, WebSphere App Server, WebSphere Liberty, z/OSMF, and much much more, I'd say it's quite the bargain. Keep in mind that is the license purchase cost if you go year to year. Annual maintenance is a fraction of that. There's a few ways to license it for a team, and depending on usage, one is more economical than another. Also, keep in mind that this moves processing off the z/OS and reduces MIPS charges during development. That could make it nearly pay for itself.

Comment: I agree with the comment above. My point was more that Hercules was/is free and there doesn't seem to be any other options for a single non-corporate developer to "play" with z/OS and Assembler.

Comment: Have you considered staring the Master the Mainframe learning system? That's a cheap (i.e. free), and easy way to learn it. https://www.ibm.com/it-infrastructure/z/education/master-the-mainframe

Comment: Just saw this old entry.  FWIW, Hercules and zD&T are two completely different sets of code. zD&T was created by IBM based on their own IC. Hercules is a reverse engineered instruction emulator, not sponsored by IBM.

Master the Mainframe does appear to be the best alternative these days.